# почему не работает код вывода картинок в цикле?

Tags: php, laravel

```html
<div class="slider single-product-nav"> @foreach($page->images as $image) <img src="{{Voyager::image($image) }}"> @endforeach </div>
```

выдает :
Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View: /home/professor/tiger/resources/views/product.blade.php)

если

```
@php 

   var_dump($page->images)
@endphp
```

показывает вроде массив

```
                                    string(103) "["products\/February2020\/ZBXpnY7bRDTkabcKqwl0.jpg","products\/February2020\/WRQPCFtYNrPsc37zT1rw.jpg"]"
```

Comment: показывает СТРОКУ, тип переменной `images` это строка, которая содержит квадратные  скобки

Comment: а как сделать это массивом чтобы это все прокрутить в цикле?

Comment: очевидно же, сделать `$images` массивом, а не строкой

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так к примеру, вариантов много:

```
$string = '["products\/February2020\/ZBXpnY7bRDTkabcKqwl0.jpg","products\/February2020\/WRQPCFtYNrPsc37zT1rw.jpg"]';

$stringWithOutBrackets = substr($string, 1, -1);
$images = explode(',', $stringWithOutBrackets);
print_r($images);
```

Вывод:

```
Array
(
    [0] => "products\/February2020\/ZBXpnY7bRDTkabcKqwl0.jpg"
    [1] => "products\/February2020\/WRQPCFtYNrPsc37zT1rw.jpg"
)
```

P.S Вариант который предложил ArchDemon будет лучше

```
$images = json_decode($string);
```

Comment: `json_decode($string)` не?!

Comment: @ArchDemon кстати да, чёт я за него даже не подумал, спасибо)